# Relation of polarity of organic functional groups and whole molecules

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, polarity

I know this should be a simple chemistry question, but I am currently very confused on how polar/nonpolar molecules work. For example, since the ether group is insoluble in water, does this mean that all molecules containing ether would be insoluable/nonpolar? Likewise, are all molecules containing alcohol group polar then?

Comment: Polarity is an *ill-defined* term which does not mean much except to organic chemists. You should rather ask yourself by looking at the structure, "Does this molecular have a dipole moment?" Learn to identify this part first.

Comment: Naming the question on chemistry forum "Simple chemistry question" is like naming a book "Simple book". Also, such a name works like a click bait, what is very disliked. I have changed it.

Comment: To further complicate things, molecules can be both polar and nonpolar. Or more precisely, have polar and nonpolar parts. Detergents are good examples of this. They have a polar group such as a sulfate, and a nonpolar group, such as a long hydrocarbon tail.

Comment: @Poutnik Wow, and here I was unsatisfied with current title, but yeah, that's a big progress actually! :D Maybe I should lower expectations...

Answer (score 3):

Groups are neither soluble neither insoluble. They contribute on substance solubility or insolubility.

Their polarity relates to dipole moments of respective chemical bonds which relate to the difference of atom electronegativities.

The effect of a group must be related to whole molecule, considering overall structure.

E.g. methanol or acetic acid are polar with unlimited miscibility with water. But $\ce{OH}$ or $\ce{COOH}$ group attached to a long alkyl chain do not make the whole molecule polar and notably soluble.

Fatty acids are not called fatty without reason. Because polarity of the group is overruled by nonpolarity of the long alkyl chain.

Note the diethyl ether solubility in water is about $\pu{6 g/100 mL}$, so the ether group is at least moderately polar, compart to the formal methylene group $\ce{CH2}$ of  n-pentane, that is practically insoluble.